# From iOS Objective-C code and Android Java code to a Codename One PeerComponent

Tags: codenameone

At the page https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-build-a-basic-app-with-gocoder-sdk-for-ios there are the following examples:

```
if (self.goCoder != nil) {
   // Associate the U/I view with the SDK camera preview
   self.goCoder.cameraView = self.view;

   // Start the camera preview
   [self.goCoder.cameraPreview startPreview];
}
```

```
// Start streaming
[self.goCoder startStreaming:self];
```

```
// Stop the broadcast that is currently running
[self.goCoder endStreaming:self];
```

The equivalent Java code for Android is reported at the page https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-build-a-basic-app-with-gocoder-sdk-for-android#start-the-camera-preview, it is:

```
// Associate the WOWZCameraView defined in the U/I layout with the corresponding class member
goCoderCameraView = (WOWZCameraView) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
// Start the camera preview display
if (mPermissionsGranted && goCoderCameraView != null) {
    if (goCoderCameraView.isPreviewPaused())
        goCoderCameraView.onResume();
    else
        goCoderCameraView.startPreview();    
}
```

```
// Start streaming
goCoderBroadcaster.startBroadcast(goCoderBroadcastConfig, this);
```

```
// Stop the broadcast that is currently running
goCoderBroadcaster.endBroadcast(this);
```

The code is self-explaining: the first blocks start a camera preview, the second blocks start a streaming and the third blocks stop it. I want the preview and the streaming inside a Codename One `PeerComponent`, but I didn't remember / understand **how I have to modify both these native code examples to return a `PeerComponent` to the native interface**.

*(I tried to read again the developer guide but I'm a bit confused on this point).*

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key line in the iOS instructions:

```
self.goCoder.cameraView = self.view;
```

Here you define the view that you need to return to the peer and that we can place. You need to change it from `self.view` to a view object you create. I think you can just allocate a `UIView` and assign/return that.

For the Android code instead of using the XML code they use there you can use the `WOWZCameraView` directly and return that as far as I can tell.